# jquery.gmap3でスクロールでのズームを無効にする

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, google-maps

googlemap3を使用し、ページ内にマップを埋め込みました。 
（独自マーカー入りのマップです。）

こちらで、ホイールスクロール機能をfalseにしたいのですが以下のコードで実装できません。 
マップの表示は成功しているのですが、オプションが効かない様子です。

> ```
> $('#gmap').gmap3({
>     address: '東京都渋谷区',
>     latitude: ☓☓.☓☓☓,
>     longitude: ☓☓☓.☓☓☓☓☓☓,
>     zoom: 15,
>     scrollwheel: false, //ここが反映されません
>     navigationControl: false,
>     mapTypeControl: false,
>     scaleControl: false,
>     markers: [
>           {
>             latitude: ☓☓.☓☓☓☓☓☓,
>             longitude: ☓☓☓.☓☓☓☓☓☓,
>             title: 'ダミー',
>             icon:  "画像へのパス",
>             openInfo: true
>           }
>      ]
> });
> ```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/bumberboom/jquery.gmap3

このライブラリは`scrollwheel`オプションの使用を想定していないようなので、`jquery.gmap3.js`を書き換えないと対応できません。

35行目から

```
function addMap($self, mpOpt) {
    var opt = {
        scrollwheel : mpOpt.scrollwheel, /* here */
        zoom : mpOpt.zoom,
        center : new google.maps.LatLng(mpOpt.latitude, mpOpt.longitude),
        mapTypeId : mpOpt.mapTypeId,
        navigationControl : mpOpt.navigationControl,
        mapTypeControl : mpOpt.mapTypeControl,
        scaleControl : mpOpt.scaleControl
    };
```

146行目から

```
    $.fn[name_space].defaults = {
        address: '',
        latitude: 0,
        longitude: 0,
        scrollwheel: true, /* here */
        zoom: 10,
        navigationControl: true,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        scaleControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        markers: []
  };
```

ちなみに名前が同じ別のライブラリがありまして、こちらは`scrollwheel`に最初から対応しているようなので代わりに試してみてもいいかもしれません。

http://gmap3.net/en/

Comment: ありがとうございました！実装無事にできました、急ぎでしたので助かりました。